# coc-java server gets crashed

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, filetype-java

I'm trying to use vim and coc to work with java. I'm new on java language and this is confusing.

I installed `coc` and  `node` to use the `coc-java` server.

Next I use `CocConfig` and write this to it:

```
{
    "java.home":"/opt/jdk-19.0.1"
}
```

Where `/opt/jdk-19.0.1` is where I installed Java locally.

After this I had a message of coc that server crash 4 times and won't we restarted again.

```
[coc.nvim] The "java" server crashed 4 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted.
```

I review the `:CocCommand workspace.showOutpu` to see what is happening and got this trace:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent, jdk.incubator.vector
[Info  - 4:46:58 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error  - 4:46:58 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent, jdk.incubator.vector
[Info  - 4:46:59 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error  - 4:46:59 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent, jdk.incubator.vector
[Info  - 4:46:59 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error  - 4:46:59 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent, jdk.incubator.vector
[Error  - 4:47:00 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
[Error  - 4:47:00 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent, jdk.incubator.vector
[Info  - 4:47:56 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error  - 4:47:56 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.concurrent
[Info  - 4:47:57 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error  - 4:47:57 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.concurrent
[Info  - 4:47:58 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error  - 4:47:58 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.concurrent
[Error  - 4:47:58 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
[Error  - 4:47:58 PM] /opt/jdk-19.0.1/bin/java exited with code: 13
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It looks like question for coc-java or a bug report to me